# how to get json_decode from ticker on cex.io api

Tags: php, api, object, json

Im using this code to get my balance from cex.io and it works gr8:

```
$bal = json_encode($api -> balance());
$bald = json_decode($bal);
```

and i get the result with this:

```
<?php  echo json_decode($bald->BTC->available); ?>
```

The thing is ... i cant get the ticker thing to work.This is the example from cex.io and its going well but i just want to get the first offer:

```
var_dump($api -> ticker('GHS/BTC'));
```

result

```
{'timestamp': '1383378967', 'bids': [['1.7', '0.30100000'], ['1.67', '0.00011000'], ['0.8', '0.02070000'], ['0.1002', '0.27748002'], ['0.1', '0.10000000'], ['0.011', '0.30500000'], ['0.009', '1.00000000'], ['0.00171', '0.00100000'], ['0.0012', '1.00000000'], ['0.00116819', '0.50000000'], ['0.001002', '33.00000000'], ['0.001001', '53.00000000'], ['0.001', '3.00000000'], ['0.00097626', '36.00000000'], ['0.0006', '85.00000000'], ['0.00058409', '0.50000000'], ['0.0004889', '0.06823960'], ['0.0003', '1.00000000'], ['0.00029204', '0.90000000'], ['0.0001', '101.00000000']], 'asks': []}
```

so to be more precise. I want just the first offer from 'bids'('1.7', '0.30100000') and the first from 'asks' and i don't know how to get em.

i try'd witht this:

```
$tick = json_encode($api -> ticker('GHS/BTC'));
$tickd = json_decode($tick->bids);
```

and:

```
$tickd = json_decode($tick->bids[0]);
$tickd = json_decode($tick->bids->[0]);
```

Im a noob so im trying this over and over again for 2 days and my head is smoking!
PLEASE HELP !!

Answer (score 0):

```
$tick = json_encode($api -> ticker('GHS/BTC'));

$bids = $tick["bids"];
$first_bid = isset($bids[0]) ? $bids[0] : null;

$asks = $tick["asks"];
$first_ask = isset($asks[0]) ? $asks[0] : null;
```

Comment: i got it with this `$cur1 = json_encode($api -> api_call('ticker',array(),false,'GHS/BTC'));` so its fine ... the next thing im stuck in is how to send a buy or sell request.

Comment: the examples are so not clear for me:
this is the thing i want to make something like the ticker encoding if possible:

PHP
`var_dump($api -> place_order('buy', 0.001, 1.7, 'BF1/BTC'));`
ARAY
`{'price': '1.7', 'amount': '0.00100000', 'time': 1383378987622, 'type': 'buy', 'id': '6219145', 'pending': '0.00100000'}`